# How do I merge commits after I have already pushed on Git?

Tags: git, merge, github, push, commit

I am new to git, I committed some changes, git told me that I need to pull first, so I pulled but my editor didn't display the modified versions, so I committed again with conflicts, I resolved the conflicts and committed again. Now I have 3 commits! (although I think the first one should not be there)

The problem is that I pushed every time after each commit. So is there a way to merge those pushed commits?

Can you please provide a step by step explanation? I have used svn and cvs before but I am very new to git

Comment: I'm confused. Could show us how does the top of your commit graph look like? (I.e. what do you see when you run `gitk`?)

Comment: You shouldn't push until you're ready to share what you have.  If you're still unsure if what is in your repo is correct (as it sounds like was the case) you shouldn't push.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you described seems unlikely as trying to commit while in conflict results in the following error:

```
fatal: 'commit' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as
appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

And if you couldn't commit the conflict then running git push wouldn't actually push the change.

You can run the following command to see what commits actually took place

```
git log --patch --color
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do what you want:

You can squash all three of those commits together with `git rebase -i HEAD~3`.  This will basically *get rid* of your bad commits and the content in your last one will be the final content.

When you run the command, an editor will pop up.  Replace `pick` in the second and third line with `squash`.  You will than need to push again with the `-f` flag.

This will work if they are your last three commits.  If they are farther behind than that.  You will need to rebase farther back and only put `squash` on the two commits you want to squash.

Comment: Rebasing like that when he has already pushed probably isn't a great idea if anybody else is working on the repository he pushed to.

Comment: @Gerry From what I understand, the op pushed his commits and now wants to edit them.  He has no other choice but to re write history.

Comment: The other choice would be choosing not to do it after realizing the possible problems caused by doing so could outweighing the initial problem.